# Deserialize dynamic XML with generics C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

Given the following XML:

```
<RESPONSE version="10">
    <RESULTS MyAttribute="1" />
</RESPONSE>
```

I can deserialize it like this:

```
[XmlRoot("RESPONSE")]
public class Response
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "RESULTS")]
    public Results Results {get;set;}
}

public class Results
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "MyAttribute")]
    public bool MyAttribute { get; set; }
}

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Response));
var result = (Response)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));
```

This works and is fine.
The problem however is that I want to deserialize the following XML as well and I don't want to duplicate the Response class, I want to use a generic approach.

```
<RESPONSE version="10">
    <SOCCER AnotherAttribute="1" />
</RESPONSE>
```

I've tried doing the following:

```
[XmlRoot("Response")]
public class Response<T>
{
    public T Data {get;set;}
}

public class SoccerRoot
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "SOCCER")]
    public class Soccer {get;set;}
}

public class Soccer
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "AnotherAttribute")]
    public bool AnotherAttribute {get;set;}
}


var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Response<SoccerRoot>));
var result = (Response<SoccerRoot>)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));
```

But this doesn't work, I've also tried to inherit the Response class but with no luck.
Im getting the following error: `<xmlns='' > was not expected.`

Am I on the right way here or is it not possible to use a generic approach when deserializing XML files?

Comment: that shouldn't work *in either case*; `[XmlRoot("Response")]` doesn't match `<RESPONSE>`. Is this actual code, or have you anonymized it? in particular, if so: the xmlns mention in the last error makes me wonder if the actual problem there has been lost in the anonymization

Comment: Ive anonymized it a bit sorry, will fix it. xmlns is not present in the xml at all, the xml is correct now, im writing from my phone so I dont have access to the code right now, but I think that you can understand the concept that Im after anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `Response<SoccerRoot>`, the expected xml layout would be:

```
<RESPONSE>
    <Data>
        <SOCCER AnotherAttribute=...>
```

which *does not* match what you have. There is no way of customizing the element name of the `T Data` *just* using attributes.

Options:

- have multiple root objects (one each for `SOCCER`, `RESULTS`, etc):

  ```
  [XmlRoot("RESPONSE")]
  public class SoccerRoot {
      [XmlElement("SOCCER")]
      public Soccer Soccer {get;set;}
  }
  [XmlRoot("RESPONSE")]
  public class ResultsRoot {
      [XmlElement("RESULTS")]
      public Results Results {get;set;}
  }
  ```
- have a single root object that has multiple first-level children (one for `SOCCER`, one for `RESULTS`, etc - each of one type

  ```
  [XmlRoot("RESPONSE")]
  public class Response {
      [XmlElement("RESULTS")]
      public Results Results {get;set;}
      [XmlElement("SOCCER")]
      public Soccer Soccer {get;set;}
  }
  ```
- use the generics approach, but lose the intermediate object so you have `Response<Soccer>` (delete `SoccerRoot` completely), and use `XmlAttributeOverrides` to customize the element name, *being sure to cache the `XmlSerializer` generated* (otherwise it will leak at an alarming rate)

Frankly, I'd go with either of the first two options and leave the third one alone.

Comment: Thanks, I will use solution number one, just wanted to see if their was any way to do this that I didn't knew about

Comment: @JOSEFtw well, there *is* `XmlAttributeOverrides` that not many people know about and *could* be used here (not conveniently, but it is possible), but it is a *very* complex tool and if used incorrectly: you'll out-of-memory very quickly; so : there's one new thing you might have found out about :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a common class which contains both the objects RESULTS and SOCCER and then based on the data one will be null and other will contain value.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //
        var xml = "<RESPONSE  version=\"1\" ><SOCCER AnotherAttribute =\"1\" /></RESPONSE>";
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Response<int>));
        var result = (Response<int>)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));

        xml = "<RESPONSE version=\"10\"><RESULTS MyAttribute = \"1\" /></RESPONSE >";
        result = (Response<int>)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

[XmlRoot("RESPONSE")]
public class Response<T>
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "version")]
    public T Version { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "SOCCER")]
    public SoccerRoot SoccerRoot { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "RESULTS")]
    public Results Results { get; set; }
}
public class SoccerRoot
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "AnotherAttribute")]
    public int AnotherAttribute { get; set; }
}

public class Results
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "MyAttribute")]
    public bool MyAttribute { get; set; }
}
```